# How to get a category from a product using the useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Good afternoon, I can't understand why I can't get the category by `catId` from the product.
That is, first I create a `useState` separately for product and category.
Then, using `axios` and `useEffect`, I get the product through my API via slug. (The product is all okay, everything is cool)
Next, I also want to get the category and I need to pass the `catId` parameter, and it does not work from the previously received product.

Below is the code:

```js
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {

  const [product, setProduct] = useState({})
  const [category, setCategory] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const {data} = await axios.get('/api/products/random-lucky-box')

      setProduct(data)
    }

    fetchProduct()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCategory = async () => {
      const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/categories/${product.catId}`)

      setCategory(data)
    }

    fetchCategory()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Название: {product.name} <br />
          Цена: {product.price}
        </p>

      </header>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**P.S.** : The API separately tested everything works, for example, if you pass a static id parameter. I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: If you want to use product in category fetch URL.
Then you should add product as a dependency in useEffect. [product]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

useEffect hook is like a lifecycle, it will be launch like a componentDidMount, if you wish to fetch categories from the product, you need to refactor your fetch category call in a method and not useEffect.

So when you fetch the product, after you got it, you can call your method to fetch category. It will be something like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const {data} = await axios.get('/api/products/random-lucky-box')
      setProduct(data)
      fetchCategory(data.categoryId)
    }
  }, [])

  const fetchCategory = async (catId) =>  {
     const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/categories/${catId}`)
    // set your state or whatever
    }
```

I don't have much time to elaborate more on the code, you might have to refactor, but the idea it's that. You should call your method when you get the product data